# check if array is in two multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two multidimensional arrays:

**Haystack**

```
$haystack = array (
  0 => array (
    "child_element_id" => 11
    "answer_id" => 15
  ),
  1 => array (
    "child_element_id" => 12
    "answer_id" => 17
  ),
  2 => array (
    "child_element_id" => 13
    "answer_id" => 21
  )
)
```

Needle

```
 $needle = array (
  0 => array (
    "child_element_id" => 12
    "answer_id" => 17
  ),
  1 => array (
    "child_element_id" => 13
    "answer_id" => 21
  )
)
```

I want to check if all the key values from array "Needle" exists in the array "Haystack". What's the best practice for this? Thank you!

Comment: Does `Needle` has constant key name?

Comment: Sorry, yes it does "child_answers" to be precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty easy using `in_array()` since needle can be an array:

```
$found = 0;
foreach($needle as $array) {
    if(in_array($array, $haystack, true)) {
        $found++;
    }
}
if($found === count($needle)) {
    echo 'all needles were found in haystack';
}
```

Or maybe:

```
$found = true;
foreach($needle as $array) {
    if(!in_array($array, $haystack, true)) {
        $found = false;
        break;
    }
}
if($found) {
    echo 'all needles were found in haystack';
}
```

You could even use `array_search()` as you can use an array for needle as well, no need to run two loops.

Using `serialize()`:

```
if(count(array_map('unserialize',
         array_intersect(array_map('serialize', $needle), 
                         array_map('serialize',$haystack)))) == count($needle))
{
                             echo 'all needles were found in haystack';
}
```

- `serialize()` the inner arrays of both arrays and compute the intersection (common inner arrays)
- `unserialize()` the result and compare the `count()` with the count of `$needle`

Answer (score 2):

**almost a solution:**
@shalvah gave a good starting point. However, in the suggested solution he forgot to loop over the elements of the `$needle` array like shown below:

```
function array_in_array($neearr,$haystack) {
  foreach ($neearr as $needle){
    foreach ($haystack as $array) {
      //check arrays for equality
      if(count($needle) == count($array)) {
        $needleString = serialize($needle);
        $arrayString = serialize($array);
        echo "$needleString||$arrayString<br>";
        if(strcmp($needleString, $arrayString) == 0 ) return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

But even so is this not completely "water tight". In cases where elements of the "needle" arrays appear in a different order (sequence) the `serialze()`-function will produce differing strings and will lead to false negatives, like shown in the exampe below:

```
$hay=array(array('a'=>'car','b'=>'bicycle'),
         array('a'=>'bus','b'=>'truck'),
         array('a'=>'train','b'=>'coach'));

$nee1=array(array('a'=>'car','b'=>'bicycle'),
         array('a'=>'train','b'=>'coach'));

$nee2=array(array('b'=>'bicycle','a'=>'car'),  // different order of elements!
         array('a'=>'train','b'=>'coach')); 

echo array_in_array($nee1,$hay); // true
echo array_in_array($nee2,$hay); // false (but should be true!)
```

**a slightly better solution**
This problem can be solved by first sorting (`ksort()`: sort by key value) all the elements of all the "needle" arrays before `serialize`-ing them:

```
function array_in_array($neearr,$haystack) {
  $haystackstrarr = array_map(function($array){ksort($array);return serialize($array);},$haystack);
  foreach ($neearr as $needle){
    ksort($needle);
    $needleString = serialize($needle);
    foreach ($haystackstrarr as $arrayString){
      if(strcmp($needleString, $arrayString) == 0 ) return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

echo array_in_array($nee1,$hay); // true
echo array_in_array($nee2,$hay); // true
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to recursively call the function? passing the processed data as a secondary attribute?

Comment: @DarylGill: Quite right! Even though I did *some* sorting in my code it will most likely not work reliably with deeper "needle" arrays. This was just a "quick shot" done on the basis of shalvahs's post. A recursive code is very likely the better approach. Maybe, you can put together a little example ;-) ...

Comment: @cars10 looping over the needle array? Isn't `$nearr` 1D while `$haystack` 2D?

Answer (score 1):

You could use this function:

```
function array_in_array(array $needle, array $haystack) {
foreach($needle as $nearr) {
  foreach ($haystack as $array) {
    //check arrays for equality
    if(count($needle) == count($array)) {
      $needleString = serialize($needle);
      $arrayString = serialize($array);
      if(strcmp($needleString, $arrayString) == 0 )
        return true;
      }
}
  return false;
}
```